# Color by Outline Level (group) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I would like to change the color of a cell based on its outline level in excel, by outline level i mean the level of the column grouping.

I am trying to use the ActiveCell.OutlineLevel property to use in a ColorByValue filter.

is this possible? or, is there a way to do this via VBA or function?

[image: colorbyvalue]

Comment: I don't think you can do it with formula, you will have to use VBA or maybe a UDF would work. Use `Columns(Range("I1").Colum).OutlineLevel" to get the right level and apply a color

Comment: how did you get the `-` on the left side?! in my version (2007/German) it is on the right

Comment: on the ribbons, you find the data tab... then expand the outline section to present you with the "Settings"  dialog box.. then uncheck the first two checkboxes ("Summary rows below detail" and "summary columns to the right"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks JMax i got the solution based on your advice!...

1- Add Conditional Formatting Rule into the cell that requires the formatting.

```
=OutlineLevel(CELL("col",CV1)) = 1
```

[image: edit formatting rule]

2- The formula references a small function that outputs the rows grouping level.

```
Function OutlineLev(inp As Integer) As Integer
OutlineLev = Columns(inp).OutlineLevel
End Function
```

Can anyone find a more elegant solution?

Comment: OK... small problem.. in my formula. how do i make the cell reference dynamic? ie... when i apply the formula to different cells the row (CV1 in my case) changes?

Comment: Glad you found the solution by yourself (and a good one -upvoted by the way). For your question, you can try to use the [COLUMNS()](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/17/rows-and-columns-excel-formulas/) formula

Comment: delete the $ signs from `$CV$1` to make it dynamic

Comment: @Hightower: I can't remember what is the delay but don't forget to accept your answer to "close" the question as soon as you can - thanks

Comment: @JMax, thanks, i did, needed to wait two days before marking my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for getting OutlineLevel of ROWS, and conditionally formatting was ...

1) in VBA module ...

```
Function OutlineLevel(inp As Integer) As Integer
OutlineLevel = Rows(inp).OutlineLevel
End Function
```

2) in Conditional Formatting Rules ...

```
=OutlineLevel(CELL("row",CV1)) =
```

for different values, I made several conditional format rules.

Very much based on earlier answer, so thank you! note the earlier answer used "OutlineLev" in VBA, and "OutlineLevel" in the conditional, which didn't work for me. Also I want to format by row, not column.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, please check that you are answering to the question. That is not your case. If you want to share your procedure, post the question and answer your question so your answer will be visible.