# Color Excel Rows By Outline Level

Tags: excel

I'm using the [outline function in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff) to create an indented bill of materials (BOM) and I'd like to automatically color the rows by their outline level.  A BOM is a list of parts in a product. For each sub assy in the BOM, it is typically indented to show the product structure and the Excel outline function works well for this.

What I'd like is for each level of the outline to be colored differently to aid in visualizing the BOM.  I can't figure out how to capture the outline level in order to apply conditional formatting to make that happen.

Frankly, I'm after just what is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400991/color-by-outline-level-group-in-excel/12404153#12404153), except my outline is by row instead of by column. I have not been successful in getting the solution offered there to work and haven't found another solution here or elsewhere online. I think there are assumptions made there that I don't understand or I'm not implementing the custom function properly.  I'm not permitted to comment on that solution for clarification, which is why I posted a new question.

Can anyone help me get that solution to work or offer an alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a better solution, but I'll leave the other because it may help someone else.

Post #4 in [this thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/227279-calculating-outline-levels-excel.html) at Mr. Excel describes how to report the outline level in a cell.  It's old, so the menu picks are different.  You get to the Define name dialog by selecting the cell, right mouse and pick Define Name from the pop up menu.

Now that I have the outline level in a cell, I was able to use regular conditional formatting rules to format the worksheet:

[Fully Colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXGW4.png)

This does require you to save it as a macro enabled workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer. It's not quite what I want, but it's an improvement.

[This section](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff#bmcustomize_an_outline_with_styles) of the Office Support article on outlines describes how to apply styles to an outline.  I had tried it, but the built in styles only change levels one and two and then only apply bold and italics.  I simply didn't see the changes.  By modifying the built in styles, they became more distinct.

That said, it only applies those styles to the lead line at each level, not to every item at each level:

[Auto Styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vubaB.png)

So, while it does help, it's not exactly what I want.  I'd really like every line to have formatting corresponding to its level in the outline.  As you can see in the image above, it's not easy to see where an outline level stops using this auto formatting.